# H1-H6 dont work in jsFiddle?

Tags: html, jsfiddle

I've noticed that in jsFiddle, the header tags (`<h1>` -- `<h6>`) don't "enlarge" (or otherwise *style*) the text as expected.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bubby4j/KURKp/

I was expecting to see the text larger, but it looks like regular text. How can I get the normal behavior back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now untick "Normalize CSS" in the "Choose Framework" section of the panel.

Answer (score 3):

jsFiddle currently forces normalize on all fiddles - I hope to have it changed to optional  mid Feb. Annoying indeed - no idea what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "doesnt work" in terms of the font size not being what you regularly see, that is because `font-size:100%` is inherited from the jsfiddle stylesheets for h2-h6.

You can redeclare your own rules with `h2 { font-size:2em; }` or any value you like in the CSS tab.